# AngularJS shows model text before loading entire page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The code below shows the {{x.film}} before loading the entire page. Once the page gets loaded, everything is perfect and {{x.film}} goes off. I need to remove that.

It comes from here: `<li ng-repeat="x in movies | filter:film | orderBy:'film'" style="list-style-type:none;"><a href="{{ x.param }}"><b>{{x.film}}</b></a></li>` from the code below.

Please refer to the attached screenshot.

```
<div class="search-box">
  <div class="input-group-lg right-inner-addon" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="movieCtrl">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
    <input type="search" ng-model="film" ng-model-options="{debounce: 250}" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Films">
    <ul ng-show="film">
      <li ng-repeat="x in movies | filter:film | orderBy:'film'" style="list-style-type:none;"><a href="{{ x.param }}"><b>{{x.film}}</b></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `ng-cloak`

```
<li ng-cloak ng-repeat="x in movies | filter:film | orderBy:'film'" style="list-style-type:none;"><a href="{{ x.param }}"><b>{{x.film}}</b></a></li>
```

Also add this to your css:

```
[ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], .ng-cloak {
    display: none !important;
}
```

As per `AngularJS ngCloak` documentation:

> When this css rule is loaded by the browser, all html elements (including their children) that are tagged with the ngCloak directive are hidden. When Angular encounters this directive during the compilation of the template it deletes the ngCloak element attribute, making the compiled element visible.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

Comment: This is the right way to do it. ng-cloak will remove the cloaking class from the elements once it is completely loaded. This way you won't see the elements while angular is loading.

Answer (score 1):

Add `ng-cloak` to your ng-app div.

Answer (score 1):

Are you fetching the movies from your controller? It looks like the problem might be that you movies are not initialized when the template loads. If that is the case, then you should consider using a resolve to fetch your data before you view/controller is actually loaded. If you are using ui router, you can do that in the state:

```
.state('yourStateName', {
    ...
    resolve: {
        movies: function($http) {
            return $http.get(....);
        }
    }
});
```

and in your controller, just inject the movies like

```
.controller('yourControllerName', [..., 'movies', function(..., movies) {
    $scope.movies = movies;
});
```

Comment: This is my favorite approach to this problem because it helps keep your controller VERY clean and focused. ng-cloak works too but it definitely has more of a 'hack' feel

Comment: Absolutely helps keep the controller clean, but it also has other advantages. For me the most important is that if I encounter errors fetching data, I can handle them and inform the end user in a much nicer way than navigating to and showing a broken view.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller you can wrap your related code inside of a

```
if(x.param) {
 // your code
}
```

This will ensure to fire the code only when there is params defined for x. I'm guessing its firing for the intermediary state of page reload.

Comment: new to angularjs. how i can do the same in above code?